Lowest-power approach for latching circuit for high-wattage load
I'm investigating the lowest power approach to have a single momentary push-button switch function as an on/off switch for a high-wattage load (13.8V, max 5A)—i.e., a single push gives power to the load, another single push cuts power to the load.
I'd rather not use a switching relay unless I absolutely have to because of the additional current draw and heat that it will add to the setup when on.
I would also prefer to use an approach that draws as little current as possible when the button is not pushed and the load is not powered.
The duty cycle will be the load being powered up to an hour (contiguous) per day, some days several hours total / at a time.  Current draw will generally be low (<0.5A) with occasional (not necessarily predictably timed) high-use peaks (max 5A) sustained for up to a few minutes at a time.
What solutions exist?  I know some of the silicon-based approaches will require finding specific parts with appropriate ratings for the load.
I'm exploring this for a particular application, and can provide more details if it would be helpful.
EDIT 2024-04-22: addressed some of the clarifications requested in the comments.

How low is low enough?  A latching relay consumes zero power unless it's changing state.

Does one push button turn the device on, and the device is turned off in another manner (perhaps another button)? Or does one push turn the button on, and a second push (perhaps a long push) turn the device off? Or do you want some other protocol? Can you use a latching push-button switch, or must it be a momentary push-button switch?

Along with the latching relay suggestion, I wonder why you care about the small dissipation from a relay, at all. If it is driven from the same voltage source that your load is also powered from then it will require a tiny fraction of the load power when active. A few hundred milliwatts compared to your ~70 watts won't even be noticed. And inactive it takes no power at all. I just don't see the problem.

Why not just use a pushbutton rated for the load current? No extra components and minimal power dissipation.

Yes, @Barry, a pushbutton would be simplest, but here I'm looking for what works when one isn't available.

@periblepsis, it's not that I "care" about the extra power.  I'm just curious what the lowest-power solutions are.  In some configurations that couple hundred mW would be missed—as I mentioned, the high power draw won't be constant when the load is powered.

@MathKeepsMeBusy, one push on, one push off is exactly what I'm after.  A momentary switch is all that's available in this situation.

@vir, I like the suggestion of a latching relay.  Want to suggest a full answer, with a circuit where a latching relay is controlled by a momentary switch?

@JonathanW. So this is just a big survey so you can scout and imagine which you like better, after seeing all your options? If so writing chapter and verse to meet with your pleasure is not very appealing (to me.) Yet there is a simple circuit that uses a single momentary PB, two fets one bjt, that can serve the need. But it could be done with 3 bjts, or 2 bjts and one fet. Or even three fets. (Or more of them just for fun.) Latching relays with the right number of poles would also work fine. But laying any of that out, along with others doing same, just for your intellectual pleasure? Not me.

@periblepsis, I have an actual application in mind, and could offer details if it'd help.  And the application doesn't care about a few hundred mW, but I guess I do.  And I don't need super verbose responses.  Your overview of two to three approaches here is already very informative, as is Michal's response, which is mostly just a photograph of a hand-drawn schematic.  It's obviously up to you what answers you provide, and what additional information you request, but if you have an aversion to satisfying people's intellectual pleasure, why are you responding to posts on this site?

More specific question posted here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/710896/single-momentary-switch-to-control-latching-relay

@JonathanW. I personally like the latching relay approach, given what I've read from you and how I interpret it. But that is, of course, a mixture of mindsets and resonances. All of which may mean nothing much of use. I'll post up a simple circuit here. It consumes power while just sitting around. The latching relay does not. So it's better. But just in case a non-relay semiconductor answer might be of some use here. I have a bunch of these. But I'll select a very low power version.

@periblepsis It is possible to construct a solid state latching relay where the only quiescent current is leakage through mosfets. It can be implemented with many mosfets, but a lot of those could be replaced with cmos ICs. I am about to head out, and I have some work to do this afternoon, but if no-one posts such a circuit, before I get to it, I will post one.

@MathKeepsMeBusy Cool. More is better. ;)

@periblepsis one definite advantage in some cases of a mechanical latching relay is that it retains its state even when power is lost. However, sometimes that is an advantage for the solid state version. One may want the latch to reset on power loss.

@MathKeepsMeBusy Indeed. It's good that you call out this distinction, too!

one push on, one push off is exactly what I'm after. A momentary switch is all that's available in this situation They make toggle push-buttons, with the button always in the same idle position. I.e. not something like "it goes deeper when on", but literally a pushbutton that has internal mechanical memory and each press toggles its state. The energy to change state is provided by the human pressing the button. IIRC C&K makes them. So not momentary: toggle and button. Electrically the simplest solution available. It won't reset to off state on loss of power. Those are custom and cost $$$.

Yes, that would be ideal, but as I said, I'm limited to a momentary push button in this situation.

This is a semiconductor version of a latching relay. It should power-up off. (But I may want to think about this a bit more.)

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I also have no idea if your load would fit this arrangement. (In the case of a relay, it's almost certain you are fine. But I never know with circuits like this when there is too little data about the load arrangements.)
That's it. Maybe it helps. Maybe not.

Do you know how much power this consumes when idle?  Seems like it'd be significant enough that I wouldn't want to use it for this application.

@JonathanW. Since I didn't know if you cared at all about it, I set R2 to 220k. At that level, it's like 60 uA. But you can multiply it by 10 and drop the current to 6 uA and it won't care. I am assuming the button is pressed for a few milliseconds for validation purposes in Spice. R5 and R6 could also be updated a bit, too. I just didn't want to put any extra thought into it. Since you weren't all that open handed about your application, I couldn't think for myself. So all I could be is some idiot.

@JonathanW. Little enough when off that you won't be able to measure it with a bargain bin 3.5-digit multimeter. It consumes less power than most lead acid batteries waste on self-discharge. Seems like it'd be significant enough How much current do you think flows from 13.8V through a 1Mohm resistor?

Here is a circuit from Mosaic Industries that, if implemented with CMOS logic gates, appears to have only leakage current when it is quiescent, i.e. not switching. (I am of course not counting the current to the load).

The single pole switch is the momentary push-button. The double pole switch determines the behavior on power-up. It can be replaced by fixed wiring if it is known in advance that one always wants the circuit to power up with the load off, or with the load on.
The quiescent current of CMOS logic gates is only the MOSFET leakage current provided the loads are drawing no current. In this circuit, all the loads of the logic gates have capacitors that block DC current.
Word of warning. I have not simulated or tested this particular circuit. (I hope to get around to it). I have in the past been disappointed with circuits that I have previously found on this site, which needed tweaking to work properly. So this circuit may need tweaking. However, at the moment, I have other things on my plate.

This latch draws nothing except leakage (nA) when load is off.


You have suggested parts for the Ns and the P that will be able to handle the load?  Will standard ¼W resistors work?

From left to right: 2n7000, BS250, IRF44Z. The 0.25W resistors are ok. Btw, this circuit isn’t controlled by one push button. You need one for On and one for Off.

Thanks!  But yes, a single momentary push-button is a constraint I have to work with here.
